# Google Drive iOS SDK with Offline Access

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on a requirement where we need to support the docs in offline mode, I am planning to integrate the Google Drive iOS SDK and I would like to know weather its possible to get Offline access of google drive using the SDK approach

Comment: But the steps which you described its a Google drive iOS app feature, my question is should I use the same functionality into my standalone iPad app using Google drive iOS sdk ? Is Google exposed go offline feature in Google drive iOS sdk or I need to write my own business logic

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive "offline" is available only for files Every file you edited or created while offline will sync back with the online version of Drive when the network connection is reestablished (click on Switch to Docs online or load an entirely new Google Drive page with a refresh).

Steps to make a file offline:

1. Go to your drive and select a file in a folder/individual file.
2. Click on "i" (information) which is next to edit, navigates to Details.
3. You will see an option "Keep me on device". Turn it on.
4. This file becomes offline available.

Check this [link](http://www.guidingtech.com/24186/google-drive-offline/) for more information.